# Why doesn't apt full-upgrade upgrade this upgradable package?

Tags: debian, apt, debian-bullseye

When I run `apt update` on my Debian 11 bullseye installation (I haven't gotten around to upgrade to bookworm), at the end of its output it says:

```
1 package can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see it
```

I then run `apt full-upgrade -a` which normally upgrades all packages, but not in this case:

```
$ sudo apt full-upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

`apt list --upgradable` shows

```
$ sudo apt list --upgradable -a
Listing... Done
unifi/stable 7.5.176-22707-1 all [upgradable from: 7.4.162-21057-1]
unifi/now 7.4.162-21057-1 all [installed,upgradable to: 7.5.176-22707-1]
```

It's a third-party package, but I don't think that should make a difference here.

`apt policy`:

```
$ apt policy unifi
unifi:
  Installed: 7.4.162-21057-1
  Candidate: 7.5.176-22707-1
  Version table:
     7.5.176-22707-1 500
        500 http://www.ubnt.com/downloads/unifi/debian stable/ubiquiti amd64 Packages
 *** 7.4.162-21057-1 100
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

There's no hold on the package:

```
$ dpkg --get-selections | grep unifi
unifi                                           install
```

I'm sure I can upgrade the package with `apt install unifi`, but I wonder why `apt full-upgrade` doesn't upgrade it.

EDIT:

If I do try to upgrade, as @A.B commented, the reason becomes clear:

```
$ sudo apt install -d unifi
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 unifi : Depends: mongodb-server (>= 1:3.6.0) but 1:3.2.11-2+deb9u1 is to be installed or
                  mongodb-10gen (>= 3.6.0) but it is not installable or
                  mongodb-org-server (>= 3.6.0) but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I kinda would expect `apt full-upgrade` to tell me that there is a problem with the package, instead of just silently ignoring it, but oh well.

Comment: If you try to upgrade it manually by stating its name (using option `-d` to only download) you might discover additional reasons.

Comment: @A.B Thanks, that indeed led to the reason.

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, the new version of the unifi package depends on a newer version of mongodb than is available in the installed version of Debian:

```
$ sudo apt install -d unifi
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 unifi : Depends: mongodb-server (>= 1:3.6.0) but 1:3.2.11-2+deb9u1 is to be installed or
                  mongodb-10gen (>= 3.6.0) but it is not installable or
                  mongodb-org-server (>= 3.6.0) but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```